# After Update Trigger puzzlement

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to get my head round an AFTER UPDATE trigger.

Currently in our DB there is a Trigger that contains a cursor. From my understanding cursors in triggers are generally bad performing, so I'm trying to get rid of the cursor.

Currently the trigger looks like this:

```
    ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_TaskMovement_Zone] ON [dbo].[Tasks_Movement] 
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @rowcheck int
    DECLARE @MovementID INT
    DECLARE @SiteFromID INT
    DECLARE @SiteToID INT
    DECLARE @SiteResponsibleID INT
    DECLARE @FromAddress_Postcode Varchar(20)
    DECLARE @ToAddress_Postcode Varchar(20)

    DECLARE zcursor CURSOR FOR SELECT ID, SiteFromID, SiteToID, SiteResponsibleID
    , FromAddress_Postcode, ToAddress_Postcode FROM inserted 

    OPEN zcursor    

    SELECT @rowcheck=1
    WHILE @rowcheck=1       
    BEGIN  
        FETCH NEXT FROM zcursor INTO @MovementID, @SiteFromID, @SiteToID, @SiteResponsibleID, @FromAddress_Postcode, @ToAddress_Postcode
        IF (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)

        BEGIN
            UPDATE  Tasks_Movement
            SET     ZoneFromID = dbo.fn_GetZoneFromPostcode(@FromAddress_Postcode),
                    ZoneToID = dbo.fn_GetZoneFromPostcode(@ToAddress_Postcode)
            WHERE   Tasks_Movement.ID = @MovementID

            UPDATE  Tasks_Movement
            SET     SiteResponsibleID = [dbo].[fn_GetDefaultDepotResponsibleForSite](@SiteFromID) 
            WHERE   Tasks_Movement.ID = @MovementID
                AND (@SiteResponsibleID Is NULL OR @SiteResponsibleID=0)
                AND (@SiteFromID Is NOT NULL AND @SiteFromID>0)

            UPDATE  Tasks_Movement
            SET     SiteResponsibleID = [dbo].[fn_GetDefaultDepotResponsibleForSite](@SiteToID)
            WHERE   Tasks_Movement.ID = @MovementID
                AND (@SiteResponsibleID Is NULL OR @SiteResponsibleID=0)
                AND (@SiteToID Is NOT NULL AND @SiteToID>0)


        END
        ELSE
            SELECT @rowcheck=0
    END

    CLOSE zcursor   
    DEALLOCATE zcursor
END
```

From what I can tell the cursor in this is completely unnecessary(?)

Would I be right in thinking that the following would work better:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_TaskMovement_Zone] ON [dbo].[Tasks_Movement] 
   AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

            UPDATE  Tasks_Movement
            SET     ZoneFromID = dbo.fn_GetZoneFromPostcode(inserted.FromAddress_Postcode),
                    ZoneToID = dbo.fn_GetZoneFromPostcode(inserted.ToAddress_Postcode)
            FROM inserted
            WHERE   Tasks_Movement.ID IN (SELECT id FROM inserted)

            UPDATE  Tasks_Movement
            SET     SiteResponsibleID = [dbo].[fn_GetDefaultDepotResponsibleForSite](inserted.SiteFromID) 
            FROM inserted
            WHERE   Tasks_Movement.ID IN (SELECT id FROM inserted
                                            WHERE (inserted.SiteResponsibleID Is NULL OR inserted.SiteResponsibleID=0)
                                            AND (inserted.SiteFromID Is NOT NULL AND inserted.SiteFromID>0))

            UPDATE  Tasks_Movement
            SET     SiteResponsibleID = [dbo].[fn_GetDefaultDepotResponsibleForSite](@SiteToID)
            FROM    inserted
            WHERE   Tasks_Movement.ID IN (SELECT id FROM inserted
                                            WHERE (inserted.SiteResponsibleID Is NULL OR inserted.SiteResponsibleID=0)
                                            AND (inserted.SiteToID Is NOT NULL AND inserted.SiteToID>0))

END
```

Comment: Please tell us what **concrete database system** this is for - many things are vendor-specific. Are you using MySQL? Postgres? SQL Server? Oracle? IBM DB2? Something else entirely? Please update your tags to show what database system (and which version of it!) you're using - thanks!

Comment: Sorry marc ... It's for SQL Server.  I've updated the tags now.

Comment: The cursor approach is slow when you are going over a large set of rows. In your case, you have only the inserted row, so removing the cursor is not the problem.

Comment: Emmad I was under the understanding that the inserted table could contain multiple rows? is this not the case?

Comment: Yes, the inserted table will contain as many rows as were updated, this could be millions, so a cursor would be slow. You are correct in trying to avoid cursors like the plague, there is almost always a set based approached that will out perform it, as with everything though they have their place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your trigger should be something like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_TaskMovement_Zone] ON [dbo].[Tasks_Movement] 
   AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    UPDATE  tm
    SET     ZoneFromID = dbo.fn_GetZoneFromPostcode(i.FromAddress_Postcode),
            ZoneToID = dbo.fn_GetZoneFromPostcode(i.ToAddress_Postcode)
    FROM    Tasks_Movement tm
            INNER JOIN inserted i
                ON i.ID = tm.ID;

    UPDATE  tm
    SET     SiteResponsibleID = [dbo].[fn_GetDefaultDepotResponsibleForSite](i.SiteFromID)
    FROM    Tasks_Movement tm
            INNER JOIN inserted i
                ON i.ID = tm.ID
    WHERE   (i.SiteResponsibleID IS NULL OR i.SiteResponsibleID = 0)
    AND     i.SiteFromID > 0

    UPDATE  tm
    SET     SiteResponsibleID = [dbo].[fn_GetDefaultDepotResponsibleForSite](i.SiteToID)
    FROM    Tasks_Movement tm
            INNER JOIN inserted i
                ON i.ID = tm.ID
    WHERE   (i.SiteResponsibleID IS NULL OR i.SiteResponsibleID = 0)
    AND     i.SiteToID > 0
END
```

I've changed it to use SQl Server's `UPDATE .. FROM` syntax, and also removed the redundant null check when you are checking if a site ID > 0. `NULL` is not greater than or less than 0, so if SiteID is null SiteID > 0 can never evaluate to true, so it is a redundant additional check.

Finally, I would also recommend removing the user defined functions, although I can't see under the hood of these, based on the name they look very much like they are simple loukup functions that could be achived much more efficiently with joins.

---

**EDIT**

Rather than using the `UPDATE(column)` function I would add an additional join to the update to filter for updated rows, e.g.:

```
UPDATE  tm
SET     SiteResponsibleID = [dbo].[fn_GetDefaultDepotResponsibleForSite](i.SiteToID)
FROM    Tasks_Movement tm
        INNER JOIN inserted i
            ON i.ID = tm.ID
        LEFT JOIN deleted d
            ON d.ID = i.ID
WHERE   (i.SiteResponsibleID IS NULL OR i.SiteResponsibleID = 0)
AND     i.SiteToID > 0
AND     AND ISNULL(i.SiteToID, 0) != ISNULL(d.SiteToID);
```

I'd do it this way because `UPDATE(siteToID)` will return true if *any* row has an updated value, so if you update 1,000,000 rows and one has a change it will perform the update on all of them, not just the ones that have changed, by joining to `deleted` you can limit the update to relevant rows.

Comment: Ah OK, that makes a bit more sense now.  Thanks for the advice Gareth.

Comment: And can I wrap these UPDATE statements with IF(UPDATE(FromAddress_Postcode) OR UPDATE(ToAddress_Postcode)) BEGIN ... END to stop it doing the update unnecessarily?

Comment: That's brilliant ... thanks for helping me out with this. It makes a hell of a lot more sense now! :)

Comment: Would the inner join on deleted stop the INSERTED records being updated this way though? IE it would only work on pure UPDATE commands not INSERT commands too?

Comment: Yes it would, you could change it to a left join and add a where clause (I have changed my previous edit to show this)